# The new software iOS 8.1.3 won't update

Tags: software-update

I have the iPhone 5s which I bought like 2 months ago. The new software update iOS 8.1.3 wont install. I press the Agree button for terms and conditions and it just wont do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating through iTunes. This is useful for those times when there isn't enough free memory available for the update to install on the device itself.

The sequence is to back up the phone and then apply the update.

If there is an error, you will see it in the iTunes update error logs. You can also restore the device to factory settings (via iTunes or via the reset options in the settings app - erase all content and settings) and then update if the cause of the error is some corruption of the apps and data on the phone.

Comment: i have tried that already and i have a 4GB free space in my phone! when i tried from itunes, it went until the end but last minute said that it cannot be done..

Comment: @andrianav. I've elaborated on the answer - it's basically a triage problem now. iTunes will log update errors and also let you clear errors from the device if needed.

Comment: @bmike. so what am i supposed to do now? (sorry for not understanding)

Comment: @andrianav. I'd start with connecting the device to iTunes and press restore. If that fails, you can ask a follow on question here if you don't know where to look for the error logs or you could just wipe the device and try updating. I'm not sure what part you are uncertain of - so asking a new question with details and linking here might be your best shot if the answer as written isn't enough detail for you.